# User is automatically being logout randomly when using session authentication in Django

Tags: django

I am using `Django version 4.1` and haven't modified any codes for authentication and have used the defaults/built-ins provided by Django itself.

I am facing issue of logging out automatically in random order when user is using my application. I tried to see the request logs during the time of logout, i even replicated it on my local computer, but i couldn't find any bugs or issue (until now) which caused this issue.

Issue replication steps (but this doesn't happen always)

- More than 2 users using the app at same time

From this question, i would like to ask

- What should i be looking for when debugging such scenarios?

Comment: Provide your logout code or anything related to your issue

Comment: Actually logging out never happens through URL, instead happens due to session token being invalid as per my investigation

Comment: Does it happen in different browsers too?

Comment: yes, i have tested it with Safari, Chrome and Brave

Comment: Then check if your cookies have been removed by JavaScript, by verifying if it's due to any code you've written or any third-party library.